# show field on select of dropdown, jquery conflict in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Nice to meet everyone.

I've started using Bootstrap which is great and I love it.  I'm opening a modal window with a form in.  In this form there is a select field.  When someone clicks 'other' it displays a field to describe more.  It works great on my laptop.  However the site being designed for mobile.  When I load it on the iphone or any phone, after other is selected you can no longer scroll down through the modal window.  It locks and the faded background scrolls instead.

Would anybody know why or maybe a simple way around the issue.  I'm sorry I hope that question is not too vage.

Here is the code I'm using for showing the new form field

```
  $('select[name=jtype]').change(function(e){
  if ($('select[name=jtype]').val() == '1'){
$('#jobName').show();
  }else{
  $('#jobName').hide();
  }
  });
```

And the form fields from the modal window.

```
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="jtype">Job  <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>  
      <div class="col-md-8 controls">
      <select name="jtype" id="jtype" required class="form-control">
    <option value="" <?php if (!(strcmp('', $_POST['jtype']))) {echo "selected";} ?>> Please Select</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if (!(strcmp('1', $_POST['jtype']))) {echo "selected";} ?>>Other</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if (!(strcmp('2', $_POST['jtype']))) {echo "selected";} ?>>Quote</option>

       </select>
      </div>
    </div>


     <div id="jobName">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="job">New Job Here</label>  
       <div class="col-md-8 ">
         <input id="job" name="job" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['job'])){ echo $_POST['job'];}?>" placeholder="Create New Job Type Here"  class="form-control input-lg">

          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! :) Can you provide a quick demo in a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @sebastianHomeier Yes sure.  Never done that so bare with me

Comment: OK so here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sL5zt4qu/  however I have tested it on my phone and its fine on the fiddle so I think thats being rendered differently.

Comment: Then something in the rest of your code may cause the issue. Do you have a link to your project?

Comment: Yes of course let me just re create the page so you dont have to log in and remove a few links ;)  one sec

Comment: Hi @SebastianHomeier I have that link to the page.  http://engineer.devonmotte.com/members/hold.php

Comment: If you click to make a booking fill in the first or second field and the time then select other from the drop down you will see a quick flicker on the phone.  It then freezes the modal window and only the background scrolls.

Comment: Strange because it works perfectly else where just fails on the only device I actually need it to work on :(

Comment: Works fine on my Nexus 5... which phone do you use?

Comment: tried it on the iphone 4, 5 and the new one

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the issue. Maybe try adding `pointer-events: none;` to `.modal-backdrop`

Comment: ok thank you anyway for trying small progress.  If I remove   
          <div class="row clearfix">
         
           <div class="col-xs-11">
             <div id='calendar'></div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
       then it works fine on the phone.  Does this mean it maybe a css issue maybe in the full cal css

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I found the answer.  It seems the Iphone has a bug with the keyboard and modals so someone has created a nice work around.  I'd post where I found it but I cant find the link anymore

```
  if( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) ) {
    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        // Position modal absolute and bump it down to the scrollPosition
        $(this)
            .css({
                position: 'absolute',
                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 'px',
                bottom: 'auto'
            });
        // Position backdrop absolute and make it span the entire page
        //
        // Also dirty, but we need to tap into the backdrop after Boostrap 
        // positions it but before transitions finish.
        //
        setTimeout( function() {
            $('.modal-backdrop').css({
                position: 'absolute', 
                top: 0, 
                left: 0,
                width: '100%',
                height: Math.max(
                    document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
                    document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
                    document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
                ) + 'px'
            });
        }, 0);
    });
}
```